# How to align enlarged CircularProgressIndicator by the enlarged circle center?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to align an enlarged Compose `CircularProgressIndicator` by its enlarged center point instead of by the center point of the original non-modified circle.

The following aligns as if `CircularProgressIndicator` were not modified at all, which is demonstrated by the attached screenshots.

```kotlin
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
}
```

[image: progress indicator aligned to non-modified center]
[image: original non-enlarged alignment for reference]

I attempted various combinations/orders of alignment modifiers to no avail. Is there a way to fix this without using a manual offset?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Modifier.aspectRatio()` to have a Composable with any defined ratio. After getting a square container for progress indicator you can center it using Box's contentAlignment field.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
        .fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {

    CircularProgressIndicator(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f)
    )
}
```

Comment: It works, but why?

Comment: @Robin When you don't assign a size Modifier it assigns size `CircularIndicatorDiameter` which is `40.dp`. By setting fillMaxWidth we set width to device width and by using aspect ratio height is set as big as width. And using outer Box you center this square `CircularProgressIndicator` vertically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am still confused. Since I was using exactly the same code in your answer, except for the aspectRatio(1f). My question is why the circular progress indicator is not vertically centered WITHOUT specifying the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the size to the `CircularProgressIndicator()`, not to the `Box()`

Try

```
                        Box(
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                        ) {
                            CircularProgressIndicator()
                        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. To be clear, I still want the modified `CircularProgressIndicator` size, but I would like its center point to be in the center of the box. My 2nd screenshot above is meant to show that the enlarged indicator is aligned using the non-modified center point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like  to center a maximum possible `CircularProgress` size is to make sure both `width` and `height` have the same value.

I put a global position listener to check its size using either`fillMaxWidth`, `fillMaxSize`, or a manual size based on `screenWidth`, the output values though are based on my phone's resolution.

`fillMaxSize` won't make sense because there's nothing more to center, the height already filled up the entire screen, while `fillMaxWidth` having a very small height value also behaves the same as there is nothing to vertically center it, looks like the centering measurement is expecting the width and height to be the same.

```
 val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
 val screenWidth = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp

 Box(
    modifier = Modifier
         .background(Color.Gray)
         .fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
 ) {
     CircularProgressIndicator(
         modifier = Modifier
             // .fillMaxSize()     =  Width:[1080] : Height:[2195]
             // .fillMaxWidth()    =  Width:[1080] : Height:[105]
             // .size(screenWidth) =  Width:[1079] : Height:[1079]
             .align(Alignment.Center)
             .onGloballyPositioned {
                 Log.e("CircularProgress", "Width:[${it.size.width}] : Height:[${it.size.height}]")
             }
     )
 }
```

So using the `screenWidth` to specify the size will make sure the `CircularProgress` take the most possible space it can equally (w,h) adjust to for it to center properly.

The code above uncommenting the `.size()` modifier call will produce the output below.

[image]